# Unsure whether image data is considered an NFT even though it doesn't extend ERC721

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, nft

I'm currently developing a project in Solidity where I have a struct of images that contain an image, title, description and a price and data gets passed into it based on what the user types in the frontend. If I where to allow users to purchase each post and sell them would they be considered an NFT or would I still have to extend ERC721 and publish the metadata somewhere?
I have tried to upload the data into a data structure rather than extend an ERC721 with metadata.
Any responses would be appreciated.

Comment: **would I still have to extend ERC721**

This is recommended yes. Although technically you don't strictly need to as long as you implement the interface through some other means. Post the ABI output from running `solc` in your question if you wish to find out.

**and publish the metadata somewhere?**

This depends on what your NFT intends to do. It isn't compulsory, but it is common, especially for NFTs that have some art/ image associated to them.

Answer (score 0):

It is 'considered' NFT as long as you use the ERC721 or ERC1155 based contract.

There are still a lot of questions in regards to the 'proper' format of metadata.

Good practice is to have a fixed (baked) metadata which is either baked in the contract or points to a JSON that is 'baked' in IPFS storage. The metadata file should point to image assets that aren't mutable and are baked on IPFS.

In your case this means that as long as the assets are only inputed once, you can bake them into a metadata JSON and place said assets on IPFS and you will have 'proper' NFTs there.

That however doesn't work for all projects. Some gaming etc projects point to centralized endpoints for metadata JSON. This allows them to maintain NFTs such as game artefacts, characters or assets with mutable parameters. This also allows to rectify problems after the contract is deployed.

The mutable metadata approach however is frowned upon by the community unless your mutability is handled by your smart contract code w/o centralized parts.

I'm surprised personally there is still no unified standard for metadata where it should be implemented as part of the Solidity smart contract logic rather than an external JSON file.

From the other point of view, it is difficult to develop such standard given that some projects take NFTs beyond the usual 'one static image hosted on IPFS'. You can look into our "Rich NFT" take on this: https://ethora.com/wiki/Rich_or_Metaverse_NFTs where basically we extend metadata with low poly, high poly 3D model as well as other parameters such as 'authors' etc.

It would be nice to have a unified community standard for NFTs metadata given the latest developments and where it also disciplines developers into storing and handling the assets and parameters in a proper decentralized way.